# Animating filling a data frame in R

Tags: r, animation

I have a dataframe/matrix in R which I am populating with random numbers in a loop. I was just curious if it was possible to "animate" this, i.e., visually demonstrating the filling-in process?

Thanks.

Comment: So you want an animated GIF or something? Maybe try describing exactly what the desired output would look like. It's hard to make recommendations with so little information about what the output should be.

Comment: You can make a table 'plot' and save it to file during each iteration of the for loop

Comment: @12b345b6b78 Could you please explain this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(gridExtra)
dataset <- matrix(100, 10, 10)
for (i in 1:10) {
  filename <- paste0('frame', sprintf("%03.f", i), ".png") 
  png(filename, height = 360, width = 360)
  # do things iteratively, for example:
  dataset[sample(1:10, 5), sample(1:10, 5)] <- as.integer(rnorm(1, 500, 50))
  grid.table(dataset)
  dev.off()
}
```

[image]